# Adding triangle pointer to the center of bottom of nav-item/menu

Tags: html, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I want to add a white triangle on the bottom of my horizontal menus once the menu get hovered/activated. The triangle however it's not align at the center of the menu but the right-most corner. If I add css "left: 50%;", it goes to the center of the menu bar(/screen). Here is the code snippet:
Html:

```
  <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-white">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-white">Privacy</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
```

css:

```
  li.nav-item a:hover::after {
        content: "";
        height: 0;
        width: 0;
        border-left: 6px solid transparent;
        border-right: 6px solid transparent;
        border-bottom: 6px solid #fff;
        position: absolute;
     /*left:50%;*/
        bottom: 0;
    }
```

Update1: as you can see in below image, the triangle is at the bottom-right corner of "Home", should be the center below the menu. Same to hover over "Privacy".
[image]

Update2: added ".text-center" to either "li" or "a" wont work.

TIA.

Comment: do you have any representation or drawings , about what you want to achieve ?

Comment: Did you forget to add `position:relative` to the `a`?

Comment: @sharun k k added screenshot

Comment: @Paulie_D "position: relative" will put the triangle about 4px up from the bottom of menu bar and it's still on the right side of menu.

Answer (score 0):

I finally used:

```
display: block; 
position: relative; 
left: 50%; 
bottom: -10px;
```

In the above CSS to make it work.

I also removed the navbar's padding and add "pt-1" to "li").
I don't know why `display: block;` worked.